# Schedule a Maintenance mode using CRON

Tags: magento2, maintenance

Does any one knows, how to create or use CRON to activate Maintenance mode in Magento? any sample script or reference will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop a cron, and create an empty file programmatically in `var` directory with the name `.maintenance.flag` then schedule your cron accordingly

And if you want to remove maintenance mode then schedule another cron to delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

If you preffer using Magento code you can use **Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode** class

For instance `$this->maintenanceMode->set(true);`